# What is the extra variable in this Swift function declaration

Tags: ios, swift

This line is from a tutorial I'm following, take a look at the second parameter. Coming from another language, the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' is unexpected. What is the purpose of that variable(in terms of the Swift language, not the iOS framework) & what is the concept of this "extra variable" called so I can do further personal research?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be odd if you are coming from Java or C# and I guess basically from any other language except Objective-C :)
In Swift there is a concept of external and internal parameters. In your example  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is external name which is 'visible' to the method caller and 'indexPath' is internal or local name which is used inside the method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See the following code:

```
func someFunction(externalParameterName localParameterName: Int) {
    // function body goes here, and can use localParameterName
    // to refer to the argument value for that parameter
}
```

from: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html  (section External Parameter Names)

**cellForRowAtIndexPath** is the name you see from outside the function, so when calling it

**indexPath** is the name inside the function, usually a shorter one.

**NSIndex** is the type